# If a file exists create a new one with a version number

Tags: vba, version

I am trying to check if a file with a given name exists and if it does create a new one with name that ends v2, then v3 and so on.

```vb
Sub checkFileExists()

    Dim strFileExists, strFileName As String
    Dim nextDay as Date
    Dim i As Integer
    
    strFileName = file_name
    strFileExists = Dir(strFileName)

    If strFileExists = vbNullString Then
        strFileName = file_name
    Else
        i = 1
        Do
            i = i + 1
            strFileName = file_name & "_v" & i
            strFileExists = Dir(strFileName)
        Loop Until strFileExists = vbNullString

        strFileName = file_name & "_v" & i
    End If
 
End Sub
```

Above code create almost always file name even if this file already exits.

```
strFileName = "Plan_" & Format(nextDay, "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

Comment: Your code isn't doing anything. Could you share what you want it to do? Describe a practical example with folder paths (e.g. `C:\Test\ `) and file names (e.g. `Test.xlsx`, `Test_v2.xlsx`).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This function will return the next unused filename version:

```
Function GetNextUnUsedVersionName(FilePath As String, Optional hasExtension As Boolean = True)
    Dim Result As String
    Dim Extension As String
    If (hasExtension) Then Extension = Mid(FilePath, InStrRev(FilePath, "."))
    Result = FilePath
    If Len(Dir(Result)) > 0 Then
        Dim n As Long
        n = 1

        Do
            n = n + 1
            Result = Left(FilePath, Len(FilePath) - Len(Extension)) & "_v" & n & Extension
            DoEvents
        Loop Until Len(Dir(Result)) = 0
    End If
    
    GetNextUnUsedVersionName = Result
End Function
```